Spring Boot JPA not inserting data in DB, while data is printed in console upon starting
I wrote this code to insert data in DB, while data is being printed in console after starting the application.
The API URL is not working, I noticed that the data is populating in DB only. I am using Spring Boot's in house H2 DB.
------ SAMPLE CLASS------
@Entity
public class sample {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String teamName;
    private long totalMatches;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public long getTotalMatches() {
        return totalMatches;
    }

    public void setTotalMatches(long totalMatches) {
        this.totalMatches = totalMatches;
    }

    public sample(String teamName, long totalMatches) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.totalMatches = totalMatches;
    }

    public sample() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Team [teamName=" + teamName + ", totalMatches=" + totalMatches;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

-----JOB COMPLETION-----
@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    private final EntityManager em;

    public JobCompletionNotificationListener(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");

            sample sampleD = new sample("abc", 20);
            if (em.contains(sampleD)) {
                log.info("----Present----");
            } else {
                em.persist(sampleD);
            }
            System.out.println(sampleD);

        }
    }
}

if (em.contains(sampleD)) {
                log.info("----Present----");

This if statement is also not working.
I am not able to understand while data is being printed in console, why data is not inserted in DB.
Need help regarding the same, is there something I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

Could you please provide minimal code to simulate the behavior? As I tried it in my local system and it worked perfectly fine, it persisted the data in DB and also printed it on the console.

I tried passing minimal data as shown in above edit, still same result, data is not persisting in DB

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, otherwise it's very hard to understand and reproduce your problem

package com.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Sample {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int empId;
    private String firstName;

}



package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo implements CommandLineRunner {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.setEmpId(2);
        sample.setFirstName("john");

        System.out.println(sample);

        try {
            Sample entity = em.find(Sample.class, sample.getEmpId());
            System.out.println("entity " + entity);

            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Present");
            } else {
                em.persist(sample);
                System.out.println("inserted");
            }
            System.out.println(sample);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

